# how to optimize a query with a lot of join

Tags: mysql, index

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s0_.id AS id0, 
    s0_.created AS created1, 
    s0_.style AS style2, 
    s0_.styleTitle AS styleTitle3, 
    s0_.styleTitleDescription AS styleTitleDescription4, 
    s0_.styleDescription AS styleDescription5, 
    s0_.styleFontCustom AS styleFontCustom6, 
    s0_.styleTitleColor AS styleTitleColor7, 
    s0_.smallCoverUrl AS smallCoverUrl8, 
    s0_.coverUrl AS coverUrl9, 
    s0_.selected_at_home AS selected_at_home10, 
    COUNT(s1_.id) AS sclr11
FROM style s0_ 
    LEFT JOIN instagram_picture_style s2_ ON s0_.id = s2_.style_id 
    LEFT JOIN instagram_shop_picture s1_ ON s2_.picture_id = s1_.id 
                                        AND (s1_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
    LEFT JOIN instagram_picture_category s3_ ON s1_.id = s3_.picture_id 
    LEFT JOIN instagram_first_level_category s4_ ON s3_.first_level_category_id = s4_.id 
WHERE 
      s4_.id = 24 
  AND s1_.isLocked = 0 
  AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    s2_.style_id 
ORDER BY 
    sclr11 DESC 
  LIMIT 10;
```

Here is my index from shopious_instagram_shop:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                           | Non_unique | Key_name                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| instagram_shop_picture |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            1 | id                 | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          0 | UNIQ_3B08DC6736AC99F1        |            1 | link               | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | IDX_3B08DC674D16C4DD         |            1 | shop_id            | A         |       39751 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | viewed_today_idx             |            1 | viewed_today       | A         |          40 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | created_idx                  |            1 | created            | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            1 | id                 | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            2 | shop_id            | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            3 | isShown            | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            4 | isStyleInspiration | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            5 | isLocked           | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | shop_shown_style_deleted_idx |            6 | deletedAt          | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | idx_locked_deletedAt         |            1 | isLocked           | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | idx_locked_deletedAt         |            2 | deletedAt          | A         |       36528 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | idx_deleted_shopId           |            1 | deletedAt          | A         |       36528 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | idx_deleted_shopId           |            2 | shop_id            | A         |      135156 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | low_res_idx                  |            1 | lowresimageurl     | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| instagram_shop_picture |          1 | media_idx                    |            1 | mediaid            | A         |     1351560 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

the rest of the table doesn't have an indexes yet

on average this query is taking me more than 15 seconds to execute. What indexes should I add to this query to make it faster?

Comment: Can u tell me present indexes you have on your tables

Comment: @PydiRaju updated the question above

Comment: Also add the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...(your query)...;` output in the question.

Comment: Please add combined index on (isLocked,deletedAt). and add another two indexes on style_id ,sclr11  separatly

Comment: @PydiRaju can you please try to elaborate more in this as an answer

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.